# Can a bypass capacitor be omitted if the IC is very close to the output cap of the supply?

Tags: pcb-design, bypass-capacitor

I was wondering if I can ommit the dedicated bypass of a specific IC if the IC is very close to the output capacitor of the supply rail?

[image]

In the image above, I have an LDO and its 0.1 µF output capacitor. The IC in the bottom corner is supposed to have its own 0.1 µF bypass. But I feel placing it would be very redundant since it's so close to the LDO's output cap. Distance between the pads are less than 1 mm.

Comment: Yes, you can. Is your LDO actually stable with no larger capacitor? Or is that just not shown?

Comment: @DKNguyen yes the LDO is advertised as "capacitor-less" but i placed a 0.1 uf anyway as it felt very odd not to have an output capacitor. Thank you good sir

Comment: @DKNguyen, please expand your comment into an answer. It's what I would have written, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as your LDO is stable with that little output capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what else is supplied by the LDO. If it's the only ic or if there are only two others, non greedy ones, then it's ok.
However if you have more ic's and stuffs taking current, switching on and off and speed is important, than I would add a 1uF next to the 0.1uF between the LDO and the ic next to it.